# Ansible install SQL Server Express 2016

Tags: sql-server, ansible

I have a problem when I tried install SQL Server Express 2016 through config.ini

Preamble

- remote server is Windows 2016 ENG with last patch
- On my disk c:\temp I have the SQL setup files, and the sql_conf.ini file.
- On the instance I have installed all modules and service needed by SQL.
- If I open a rdp session on the server and run the command 'c:\temp\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE
  /configurationfile=c:\temp\sql_conf.ini' it's works withous any
  problem.
- the user that Ansible use to connect is named "ansible" and is on Administrators group.

The playbook is:

```
- name: 'Installo SQL Server Express 2016'
  win_shell: 'c:\temp\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE /configurationfile=c:\temp\sql_conf.ini'
  args:
     chdir: 'c:\temp'
```

Result is:
**There was an error generating the XML document. Error result: -2068774911**

I tried replace **win_shell** with the modules **win_command** and **win_psexec** but not have any change.
I also tried with directive **become_method: runas** but nothing change.

After many tries, I found this behavior:
If a login, only one time on remote server, via rdp with "ansible" user, (and then logoff) the palybook work without any problem!

I have found a workaround using **win_dsl** module (and not the sql_conf.ini file), but I would like understand why with the modules **win_shell**, **win_command** and **win_psexec**, not work.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: Intriguing, but nearly impossible to debug. how do you "logoff"? you just dropped the RDP connection or you actually logged off the user?

Comment: Open from my laptop client a normal msrdp session, logon with user "ansible" then, when I saw the remote screen, disconnect my user session.

Comment: Windows already has ways of deploying remotely, eg Powershell DSC. [Install SQL Server with PowerShell Desired State Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-with-powershell-desired-state-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15) describes how to do this and Ansible's [DSC docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_dsc.html) show how to combine the two. Also [Using the Win_DSC module in Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/blog/using-the-win_dsc-module-in-ansible)

Comment: If you google for this specific error, you'll see it can be caused by having insufficient privileges to install. In this case, the installation is performed by the account that runs the Ansible playbook. Does that account have the required permissions?

Comment: You can check the setup log in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\1xxx\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt` too

Comment: Yes the user have all permission right. If I open a rdp session on the server with the user "ansible" and run the command 'c:\temp\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE /configurationfile=c:\temp\sql_conf.ini' it's works without any problem.

Comment: The stange behavior is: If a login, only one time on remote server, via rdp with "ansible" user, and restart my palybook, it work without any problem!

Comment: Yes with win_dsc work well.